# Firestore security rules: check if array contains strings different from user's ID

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know how to check if an array contains a given string (as explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835481/firestore-security-rules-searching-for-a-users-id-in-array-in-a-document)). My requirement however is different: I have a document with an array *updatedByHistoryArray* written at server side that contains the history of the ids of all users who updated such a document, for example *[id1, id2, ..., idn]*.

I would like to allow a delete operation for this document only if the latter has been updated exclusively by the user who wants to delete it.
So, for example, if a user with id24 wants to delete a document, the updatedByHistoryArray of this document has to be [id24, id24, ..., id24].

Is it possible to implement this requirement in the security rules of Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds possible.  Try using [hasOnly()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly) to see if the list field contains only a single user ID.

```
resource.data.updatedByHistoryArray.hasOnly([request.auth.uid])
```