# Firestore rules: Allow list operation only if filtered by ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Me and my team are wondering how to correctly write security rule in firestore,
which allows **list** operation only if **filtered by id** like so:

First one should succeed

```
db.collection('questions')
  .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', allowedIds)
  .get()
```

Second one should fail

```
db.collection('questions')
  .get()
```

Currently we are doing this with the following rule:

```
match /questions/{question_id} {
  allow list: if question_id != null
}
```

And for now it works

However we get the following **WARNING** in the firebase console:

```
WARNING The sub-expressions are not comparable, so this comparison will always return true.
```

---

Which is weird, because for now it works (in the emulators) - which means in this case it returns **false**

So here are a few questions:

- Is this the correct way to achieve our goal?
- How long will this work (will it stop working in future versions)?
- If this is wrong - what is the correct way to do it?
- Is this discrepancy between emulators and production environment?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835481/firestore-security-rules-searching-for-a-users-id-in-array-in-a-document

Comment: Sadly, no. In their case they use the uid of the user making the request and try to check if it is present in another collection/sub-collection. In our case we want to determine how the request is done Both of the requests in my first two snippets will be checked by the `allow list: if ... ` clause, and if not filtered by id - the document id (i.e. `question_id`) will not be present.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, only authentication check suffices in Firebase security rules as an alternative for protecting list operations.

I had the same issue and reflections. Unfortunately, [`request.query` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query) do not contain any information about `where`.

After a research, in my opinion, we do not need this rules complexity when App Check is configured and enforced.

With App Check enforced, user can execute queries to Firebase only from our application, queries which were coded by developer. For this reason, we must put more effort on protecting application code integrity and quality, as nobody externally to application will not be able to query documents.

However, if we need to protect a scope of documents in a collection, we must add authorized user ids inside document and check if requester uid is in document (i.e. `authorId`).